# the VCdim of class of double parameter threshold functions

Tags: vc-theory, pac-learning

Let $H$ be a family of classifiers such that $H=\{ h_{a,b} : a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ where $h_{a,b}(x,y)=1$ iff $x\geq a$ and $y\geq b$.

I've proved that for $C=\{m=(x,y)\}$, $H$ shatters $C$.

However, when I try to choose $$C=\{m_1=(x_1,y_1), m_2=(x_2,y_2)\}$$ such that (w.l.o.g) $x_1<x_2$ and $y_1<y_2$, there is no classifier $h\in H$ such that $h(m_1)=1$ and $h(m_2)=0$.

Does this mean the VCdim of $H$ is 1? or is there a way to configure some $h\in H$ such that $h(m_1)=1$ and $h(m_2)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume w.l.o.g that $x_1<x_2$ and $y_1<y_2$. But you also don't need generality: you only need to find *one* set of 2 points that $H$ shatters to show that the VC dimension is at least 2.

Comment: Are you certain? the definition of shatters states that $H$ shatters $C$ if $|H_C|=2^{|C|}$ (contains all possible combinations). regarding what I'm trying to show, simply put that if we take 2 points in 2D $m_1 , m_2$ where $d(m_1) < d(m_2)$ ($m_1$ is closer to $(0,0)$ than $m_2$), there's no $h\in H$ thats able to categorize $h(m_1)=1$ and $h(m_2)=0$, doesnt this mean that $VCdim(H)=1$?

Comment: Yes. My answer doesn't yet try to show that any set is (or isn't) shattered; _that_ requires showing that _every_ labeling can be realized, but VC dimension just requires _one_ set of the size that is shattered. // Try {(0,1),(1,0)}; I claim that this set of size 2 is shattered (and proving that takes four cases).

Comment: I see your point, than to show that $VCdim(H)=d$ I must show some group $C$ of points s.t. $|C|=d$ that $H$ shatters, but what about the $|C|=d+1$ part? must I show that for any $C$ of size $d+1$, $H$ doesnt shatter $C$?

Comment: @Aishgadol yes, that's it

Comment: I'm quite uncertain on how to prove that the $H$ cannot shatter $|C|=3$, I'm required to choose 3 arbitrary points, Yet i'm unsure on how to position them in order to show that theres not $h\in H$ which gives the correct assignment, care to direct me in this?

Comment: @Aishgadol the $|C|=2$ case that you analyzed says that $H$ cannot shatter points whose joining line has positive slope. So split into cases for $|C|=3$: either two of the three points are in such a configuration (and you already know the rest of the argument), or not (and you need a new argument: a labeling of such points that cannot be realized). To make that rigorous, you could assume wlog $x_1\le x_2\le x_3$, and then consider whether $y_1> y_2 >y_3$.